# Can't reach - 404 - my deployed Spring Boot App on DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-deployment, digital-ocean, droplet

I deployed a simple app to test it, I've succeeded in deploying it and it runs normally. But When I try accessing it responds with 404.

After I run it

[image]

When I try to access http://<MY_IP>:8888/ or http://<MY_IP>:8888/cayan, I get

[image]

Am I missing something?

Thanks & Appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Have you allowed traffic to your droplet (vm) on the specified port in the firewall?

Comment: @tbjorch how can I do that? also isn't it enabled by default?

Comment: First of all, try using netcat or something and see if you can establish a tcp connection. E.g. `nc -v <ip>:8888`

If that succeeds, then the networking is fine. If so, then the error is somewhere closer to the application.